# How to pass data to another screen with bloc -Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, aws-amplify, bloc

**How to transfer data from one screen to another using bloc** and save , I would like to create a user profile where  I have two screens, two steps to creating a profile. I created two blocs for each class, in one I have an avatar, city and name, in the other only description. I used an amplify and when I save the first screen and  when I go to the second one, delete the data from the first screen. **How do I save everything? without delete?** after save second screen.

**First screen:**

```
 class ProfileBloc extends Bloc<ProfileEvent, ProfileState> {
 final DataRepository dataRepo;
 final StorageRepository storageRepo;
 final _picker = ImagePicker();

ProfileBloc(
  {User? user,
  required bool isCurrentUser,
  required this.storageRepo,
  required this.dataRepo})
  : super(ProfileState(user: user, isCurrentUser: isCurrentUser)) {
// storageRepo
//     .getUrlForFile(user!.avatarKey)
//     .then((url) => add(ProvideImagePath(avatarPath: url)));

ImageUrlCache.instance
    .getUrl(user!.avatarKey)
    .then((url) => add(ProvideImagePath(avatarPath: url)));
}

@override
Stream<ProfileState> mapEventToState(ProfileEvent event) async* {
if (event is ChangeAvatarRequest) {
  yield state.copyWith(isImageSourceActionSheetVisible: true);
} else if (event is OpenImagePicker) {
  yield state.copyWith(isImageSourceActionSheetVisible: false);
  try {
    final selectedImage =
        await _picker.pickImage(source: event.imageSource);
    if (selectedImage == null) return;
    final imageKey = await storageRepo.uploadFile(File(selectedImage.path));
    final user = state.user!.copyWith(avatarKey: imageKey);

    String? imageUrl;
    await Future.wait<void>([
      dataRepo.updateUser(user),
      storageRepo.getUrlForFile(imageKey).then((value) => imageUrl = value)
    ]);

    yield state.copyWith(avatarPath: imageUrl);
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
} else if (event is ProvideImagePath) {
  if (event.avatarPath != null)
    yield state.copyWith(avatarPath: event.avatarPath);
} else if (event is ProfileCityChanged) {
  yield state.copyWith(userCity: event.city);
} else if (event is ProfileNameChanged) {
  yield state.copyWith(userName1: event.name);
} else if (event is SaveProfileChanges) {
  // handle save changes
  yield state.copyWith(formStatus: FormSubmitting());
  final updatedUser2 =
      state.user!.copyWith(city: state.userCity, name: state.userName1);
  try {
    await dataRepo.updateUser(updatedUser2);
    print(updatedUser2);
    yield state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionSuccess());
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    yield state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionFailed(e));
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
}
}
```

**Second screen:**

```
class Profile2Bloc extends Bloc<Profile2Event, Profile2State> {
 final DataRepository dataRepo;
// User? user;
//   String ?get userCity => user!.city;
//   String? get userName1 => user!.name;

Profile2Bloc(
    {User? user, required bool isCurrentUser, required this.dataRepo})
     : super(Profile2State(user: user, isCurrentUser: isCurrentUser));

 @override
 Stream<Profile2State> mapEventToState(Profile2Event event) async* {
  if (event is ProfileDescriptionChanged) {
    yield state.copyWith(userDescription: event.description);
   } else if (event is SaveProfile2Changes) {
    yield state.copyWith(formStatus: FormSubmitting());
  final updatedUser =
  state.user!.copyWith(description: state.userDescription);
  try {
    await dataRepo.updateUser(updatedUser);
    print(updatedUser);
    // print(userDescribe);
    yield state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionSuccess());
  } on Exception catch (e) {
    yield state.copyWith(formStatus: SubmissionFailed(e));
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
}
}
```

**Data Repo:**

```
 Future<User> updateUser(User updatedUser) async {
   try {
     await Amplify.DataStore.save(updatedUser);
     return updatedUser;
    } catch (e) {
       throw e;
      }
      }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?
You haven't posted widget classes but before going back you just need to send a new event to Bloc and pass data inside it, then within Bloc class in mapEventToState check for the event and save data. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Hi, I stopped using Bloc and started GetX, because it was problem with overwrite data in amplify. But thanks for answer ;))